# ParamGridBuilder in PySpark does not work with LinearRegressionSGD

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, linear-regression, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I'm trying to figure out why `LinearRegressionWithSGD` does not work with Spark's `ParamGridBuilder`. From the Spark documentation:

```python
lr = LinearRegression(maxIter=10)
paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder()\
.addGrid(lr.regParam, [0.1, 0.01]) \
.addGrid(lr.fitIntercept, [False, True])\
.addGrid(lr.elasticNetParam, [0.0, 0.5, 1.0])\
.build()
```

However, changing `LinearRegression` to `LinearRegressionWithSGD` simply does not work. Subsequently SGD parameters are also unable to be passed in (such as iterations or minibatchfraction).

Thanks!!

Comment: Wasn't the answer useful? If yes, kindly accept it - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are trying to mix functionality from two different libraries: `LinearRegressionWithSGD` comes from `pyspark.mllib` (i.e. the old, [RDD-based API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/mllib-guide.html)), while both `LinearRegression` & `ParamGridBuilder` come from `pyspark.ml` (the new, [dataframe-based API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-guide.html)).

Indeed, a few lines before the code snippet in the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-tuning.html#train-validation-split) you quote (BTW, in the future it would be good to provide a link, too) you'll find the line:

```python
from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression
```

while for `LinearRegressionWithSGD` you have used [something like](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/mllib-linear-methods.html#linear-least-squares-lasso-and-ridge-regression):

```python
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint, LinearRegressionWithSGD, LinearRegressionModel
```

These two libraries are *not* compatible: `pyspark.mllib` takes RDD's of `LabeledPoint` as input, which is not compatible with the dataframes used in `pyspark.ml`; and since `ParamGridBuilder` is part of the latter, it can only be used with dataframes, and not with algorithms included in `pyspark.mllib` (check the documentation links provided above).

Moreover, keep in mind that `LinearRegressionWithSGD` is [deprecated](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html?highlight=linearregressionwithsgd#pyspark.mllib.regression.LinearRegressionWithSGD) in Spark 2:

> **Note**: Deprecated in 2.0.0. Use ml.classification.LogisticRegression or LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS.

**UPDATE**: Thanks to @rvisio's comment below, we know now that, although **[undocumented](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/regression/LinearRegression.scala#L62)**, one can actually use `solver='sgd'` for `LinearRegression` in `pyspark.ml`; here is a short example [adapted from the docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.regression.LinearRegression):

```python
spark.version
# u'2.2.0'

from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression

df = spark.createDataFrame([
     (1.0, 2.0, Vectors.dense(1.0)),
     (0.0, 2.0, Vectors.sparse(1, [], []))], ["label", "weight", "features"])
lr = LinearRegression(maxIter=5, regParam=0.0, solver="sgd", weightCol="weight") # solver='sgd'
model = lr.fit(df) # works OK
lr.getSolver()
# 'sgd'
```

Comment: Wrong link for deprecation warning [Deprecation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html?highlight=linearregressionwithsgd#pyspark.mllib.regression.LinearRegressionWithSGD)


But it looks like for using `LinearRegression` you can set the `solver=sgd` and continue working from there as if you were using `LinearRegressionWithSGD`?

Comment: @rvisio 1) Can't see your point - both our links pointers are the same 2) according to the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/regression/LinearRegression.scala#L62) (the docs are *hopelessly unhelpful* on this), the only acceptable args for `solver` are `"l-bfgs"`, `"normal"` and `"auto"`; have you actually tried `solver="sgd"` and it worked?

Comment: Your link is taking me to LogisticRegression vs. LinearRegression (the deprecation note also references Logistic). Only mentioning since the original question was related to LinearRegression

I am able to do something like `newLR = LinearRegression(maxIter=10, solver="sgd")` without errors, and then build a ParamGrid using newLR but have not yet tested running with `CrossValidator`

Comment: @rvisio oopsss... you're right for the link (corrected), as well as for `solver='sgd'` (nice catch) - see update

Comment: I dont think solver='sgd' actually works though... the following code ran fine for me as well :(

`lr = LinearRegression(maxIter=5, regParam=0.0, solver="madeup", weightCol="weight")`

`model = lr.fit(df)`

`>>> lr.getSolver()
'madeup'`

Do you have any recommendations for cross validating LinearRegressionSGD in spark?